# Jquery regex on text

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to split a paragraph of text into its sentences using jquery. However I met with some cases in which the sentences will be split wrongly.

Cases such as below

My answer was 5.6 of the answers were wrong.

Given above case, if there is no space, the two sentences cannot be split.

Currently the way I am doing it is just finding index of the period, which doesnt work. Is there any way to do it using the regex match method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you gonna have to be more specific, your question is not clear at all. Paste an example of your string and what is the desired output, as well as what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `'.'` that follow by space. Like this:

```
var paragraph = 'se tenc one. se tenc two. se tenc 5.6 one. ';
var sentenses = paragraph.split(/\.[ ]+/g); 
alert(sentenses);
```

It will show `se tenc one,se tenc two,se tenc 5.6 one,`.

Now you can add other sentense ending character like `'!?;'`.

```
var paragraph = 'se tenc one. se tenc two. se tenc 5.6 one. ';
var sentenses = paragraph.split(/[\.!?;][ ]+/g); 
alert(sentenses);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sentence splitting is an exception-filled problem. Consider this:

> Those were dark times for Mr. Grumpy, and he was properly ticked off.

Most people look for periods that are followed by some spaces, and not preceded by some special words known to be acronyms like `Mr`.

```
(?<!Mr|Mrs|Dr)\.\s+
```

then `split` on this.

Even this is not really all that great, as it doesn't account for random initials, so `James T. Kirk` will defeat it. If you disallow that (`(?<!Mr|Mrs|^[A-Z]|\s[A-Z])` in the lookbehind), then you can't prevent sentences that end in a single letter (`Look at exhibit B.`).

Hard.